# Docker elastic stack cannot receive connection error

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have docker-compose file looking like below

```
version: '3'
services:
  redis:
    build: ./docker/redis

  postgresql:
    build: ./docker/postgresql
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    env_file:
      - .env

  graphql:
    build: .
    command: npm run start
    volumes:
      - ./logs/:/usr/app/logs/
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - "redis"
      - "postgresql"
    links:
      - "redis"
      - "postgresql"

  elasticsearch:
    build: ./docker/elasticsearch
    container_name: elasticsearch
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
    depends_on:
      - "graphql"
    links:
      - "kibana"

  kibana:
    build: ./docker/kibana
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    depends_on:
      - "graphql"
    networks:
      - elastic
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch:9200

  metricbeat:
    build: ./docker/metricbeat
    depends_on:
      - "graphql"
      - "elasticsearch"
      - "kibana"
    networks:
      - elastic
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch:9200

  packetbeat:
    build: ./docker/packetbeat
    depends_on:
      - "graphql"
      - "elasticsearch"
      - "kibana"
    networks:
      - elastic
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch:9200

  logstash:
    build: ./docker/logstash
    ports:
      - "9600:9600"
    volumes:
      - ./logs:/usr/logs
    depends_on:
      - "graphql"
      - "elasticsearch"
      - "kibana"
    networks:
      - elastic
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch:9200

networks:
  elastic:
    driver: bridge
```

When I run docker-compose build and docker-compose up, I get "unable to revive connection: http://elasticsearch:9200" from every container. I don't think any of the containers are able to talk to each other right now. However, it really feels like everything should work because I have exposed all the ports for elastic components, linked them with same networks and URL is also pointing to the correct alias. What am I doing wrong?

The dockerfile settings are all correct as each container runs correctly in isolation - just not able to talk to each other at all

Comment: can it be because your elasticsearch container doesnt make use of the networkbridge?

Comment: @RutgerVk I thought that must be it but even after adding elasticsearch to the network, health checks are still failing TT

Comment: and if you add postgressql andgraphql to the network?

Comment: Please check the elasticsearch logs. There are some startup checks that must be met, otherwise elasticsearch will not start (mem locking and number of file handles). It would be helpful to have some logs of the elasticsearch container for that.